# Loop the properties of a js class

Tags: javascript, loops, properties

Lets say:

```
function person(){
    this.name = null;
    this.lastname = null;
    this.age = null;
    this.height = null;
}
```

How can I iterate through the properties?

Something like:

```
foreach(properties as property){
     console.log ( property.nameoftheproperty, property.valueoftheproperty);
}
```

Comment: try `for (var x in person) {x, person[x]}` or `Object.keys(person)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for..in` loop, like this

```
function Person(){
    this.name = null;
    this.lastname = null;
    this.age = null;
    this.height = null;
}

var person = new Person();
for (var key in person) {
    console.log(key, person[key]);
}
```

**Output**

```
name null
lastname null
age null
height null
```

Answer (score 0):

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
for(var prop in properties) {
    console.log(properties[prop]);
}
```